# Is possible to override History.push method of React-Router-Dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I want to attach a computed value of query string into URL whenever user navigates with `history.push` method.

here is my code

```js
let pusher: null | ((a: unknown, b?: unknown) => void) = null;

/**
 * This hook will push a hashed value of query string of the url
 * 
 * Don't mind about memory leak, it's `Singletom`
 * @param history an instance of History from useHistory
 * @returns `Pusher` an enhance version of `History.push`
 */
export default function useHashPusher(history: ReturnType<typeof useHistory>){

    const sha256 = useSha256();

    if(!pusher) {
        pusher = function(...args) {
            const data = args[0];
            if(typeof data === 'object' && data && 'search' in data){
                const raw = data['search' as keyof typeof data];
                if(raw){
                    const hashed = sha256.hash(raw);
                    (data['search' as keyof typeof data] as string) = `${raw}&hash=${hashed}`;
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
            console.log('overrided!', args[0]);
            history.push(...args);
        };
    }
    
    return pusher;
}
```

It works OK but I have to update code at many place from `history.push` to my `pusher`

Is there any way to override the `history.push` method? I'm using react-router-dom v5

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` and `history` are you using? What specific router is wrapping your app? You could probably create a custom `history` object with the `push` method decorated with the behavior you need here.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm using v5. The previous codes use `history.push`. What is different when creating a custom `history` object? I still need update at many place.

Comment: Well, ideally I think you could create the custom history object with your custom push method and pass that to the router ***to be*** the "global" history object used by the router and the routing context it provides. The goal being that you would access `history` like normal, i.e. `const history = useHistory()` and you'd get *your* custom history object to use. I've not tested this, but I think it might work.

Comment: I see. A good idea :D I will try and give you feedback soon.
Thank you so much bro.

Comment: It's late for me, but now you've got my interest piqued. I'll test this idea out in the morning and also get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like my commented suggestion does work. In a separate file create and export a custom `history` object.

Example:

```
import { createBrowserHistory, History } from "history";
import { sha256 } from "../path/to/sha256"; // *

const historyBase = createBrowserHistory();

const history: History = {
  ...historyBase,
  push: (...args) => {
    const data = args[0];
    if (typeof data === "object" && data && "search" in data) {
      const raw = data["search" as keyof typeof data];
      if (raw) {
        const hashed = sha256.hash(raw); // *
        (data[
          "search" as keyof typeof data
        ] as string) = `${raw}&hash=${hashed}`;
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
    console.log("overrided!", args[0]);
    historyBase.push(...args);
  }
};

export default history;
```

* ***Note:** The `useSha256` hook won't work here for this, but since I wasn't able to find any NPM package that provided this hook I am assuming this is a local custom hook. If this is the case then import the object the hook was previously.*

Import the low-level base `Router` component from `react-router-dom` and your custom `history` object and pass `history` as a prop.

Example:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import history from './history';
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

At this point the router is using *your* `history` object in it's context, so all navigation actions will use it. This means not only directly accessing `history` in nested children, but `Link` and other components that take a `To` object argument as well.

Example:

```
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handler = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/test",
      search: "?....."
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      <ul>
        ...
        <li>
          <Link to={{ pathname: "/foo", search: "?....." }}>
            Foo
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" onClick={handler}>
        Navigate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit is-possible-to-override-history-push-method-of-react-router-dom]

[image]